# why create non kosher animals?

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, animals, creation

why did hashem create non kosher animals, was it to tempt us and see if we would control ourselves?

Comment: Carrot monster, You're asking very interesting questions. Could you please try to pick out matching tags for them, not just generic things like torah or torah-study? Also, if you see red underlined words when you're typing your question in, it might mean that you need to check their spelling.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10616

Answer (score 20):

That is one reason, sure; in general, Hashem gave us rules of what to do and not to do, in order to refine us ([Bereishis Rabbah 44:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&st=&pgnum=102)).

But aside from that, the various non-kosher animals have their roles to play in the ecosystem - as predators, scavengers, etc. Also, some of them are also useful to us in capacities other than food: consider horses, camels, etc.

Comment: horses and camels are not kosher? Muslims eat that

Comment: @Jim, Yes, horses and camels are not kosher. [Muslims do not keep the laws of kosher.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Islamic_and_Jewish_dietary_laws)

Answer (score 12):

The Gemara in Eruvin says that both the cat and the ant (which are non-kosher animals) exists in order for us to learn from their character traits.

Answer (score 8):

If there are no non-kosher animals, you can't get reward for not eating them.

Answer (score 3):

maybe to get a bigger reward for making the right choice and eat kosher

Answer (score 1):

1. The cycle; blank eats blank and blank which eats blank...
2. There is also a mitvah to not eat it.

Comment: Pio, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks for all your participation!

Answer (score 1):

Non-Jews have the right to eat as well, so why wouldn't God create animals for them to eat.

Answer (score -3):

Speculation here. As pets? I guess creating humans through evolution leave tons of side products.

I surely am glad cute kittens are not kosher.

Comment: The premise of this question is that everything G-d creates has a purpose. Unless you'd like to challenge that premise from a Jewish perspective, this answer does not really address the question. Alternatively, if you can find a Jewish source for "As pets", then that might work.