# What conditions would render plants non-kosher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, agriculture

Under certain conditions, I know that uncontaminated (e.g. no insects / meat, etc) plant-based foods are prohibited (ie., non-kosher).
Examples I can think of include:

1. Non-kosher wine
2. Chometz during Pesach and
3. Plants harvested on the sabbatical/shmita year

What other conditions would render uncontaminated plant-based foods non-kosher?

Comment: Orla? Kilayim? Tevel+? Hekdesh?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10616/759

Comment: What if the plant was going to die within 12 months?

Answer (score 3):

I'm making this a "community wiki" post so others can edit it more easily (and I don't get reputation points for it). Please edit!

---

- *Tevel*.
- *Orla* - tree fruit harvested within 3 years of planting.
- *R'vay*, *t'ruma*, *peret*, etc., depending on circumstances.
- *Nosar*, *pigul*, *lan baazara*, etc.
- *Kil'ay hakerem* - different types of food grown together.
- *Tikroves avoda zara*.
- *Ir hanidachas*.
- *Ashera* - tree planted for idolatry.
- *Arbaa minim* and *s'chach* and *Sukka* decorations on *Sukos*. (*S'chach* can't be food anyway, but if you wanted to eat it, you couldn't.)
- *Shvi'is* after *zman habiur*
- *Bishul Akum*.
- *Picked on Shabbos*.
- *Grown in a dead body?*

Comment: hekdesh, nidrei issur, nazir?

Comment: Arguably, chometz she'avar alav hapesach is not excluded in the question.

Comment: Can brief translations for some of these terms be added?